# Get the user data of from facebook Login in iOS app

Tags: ios9, facebook-ios-sdk

I have managed to fetch the user's data through facebook login via SafariViewController which seems to be default way in iOS app though the native Facebook app is installed.  where as in Android the Native Facebook app gets opened and the user details are been fetched.so, how do i get the same user details via Opening the Native Facebook App by dismissing the SafariViewController.

Comment: On iOS 9, the SDK *always* uses `SafariViewController` so that it doesn't need to leave the app.  You can fetch user data after authentication.  Check the SDK documentation.

Comment: As an aside, adding language tags on questions that have nothing to do with a particular language should have the questioner immediately banned from SO.  Not that I'm bothered or anything...